# Approach to launch Alexa in-built on Samsung TV with remote key press

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, infrared

I am looking ways to launch the Alexa app on Samsung TV with a button press.
As on today, we see buttons for hulu, Prime apps, but do not see for Alexa app. I want to know if there is any way out that helps in launching specific (Alexa) app by a button press on Samsung TV remote.

I tried to explore if there is any button mapper approach on Tizen OS based Samsung TV, but could not find any.